# How MAP member function are different from member function of Object Type in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am curious about MAP keyword given to member function of Object type and wish know about how MAP member function are different from member function of Object Type in Oracle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MAP` member function are special functions used to compare objects. "Ordinary" member functions are for your own usage.

The real comparison is more between [`MAP` member functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#i460525) and [`ORDER` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7091).

You can define either one or the other for your objects. It will be **automatically** called when you compare two objects using the relational operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, ... as well as when performing *implicit* comparison using `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, `UNION`, and `ORDER BY` clauses.

But:

- The former one will define ordering of your object by mapping them to a *scalar* value
- The later will force you to programmatically  define comparison rules  *between two objects*.

MAP member function implies an absolute ordering, whereas ORDER method will use relative ordering.

Comment: Can we use Ordinary  member function for comparing because it also can return value which we can use for comparing objects?

Comment: @AmolPatil The key point here is those methods are **automatically** called by Oracle when it needs to compare two (or more) objects. You don't have to _explicitly_ call them.

Comment: ohh..Now my doubt is clear Thank you Sylvain Leroux.